# How can we toggle nested mat selection list items in an optimal way

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create expandable nested lists (if it has subLists), which on toggle should open/close subLists.

On selecting other sibling lists should open its subitems and close other subitems which are already opened and vice-versa.

I have created all above features which are working perfectly fine, but one problem is that, `toggling the parent list again the background color` doesnt go away.

Is there any way to improve this code?

Here is the typescript code:

```
constructor(
  ) {
    this.menuList = [
        {
        "name": "Angular",
        //  "subMenu": ["Anguler 1", "Angular 2"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Javascript",
        "subMenu": ["Jquery", "Ajax"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Bootstrap",
        "subMenu": ["BootStrap 2", "BootStrap 3"]
      }
    ]
  }

  onChange(e) {
    // console.log(this.selectedOpt);
    this.selected = this.selected === e.selectedOptions.selected[0].value ? null : e.selectedOptions.selected[0].value;
    // console.log('selected', this.selected, this.subItems);
    // this.subItems[this.selected.name] = null;
    if (this.selected && (!this.subItems[this.selected.name] || this.subItems[this.selected.name].length > 0)) {
      // console.log('inside if');
      this.subItems[this.selected.name] = this.selected.subMenu ? this.selected.subMenu : null;
    }
    else {
      // console.log('inside else');
      if(this.selected) {
        this.subItems[this.selected.name] = null;
      }
      else {
        // console.log('isnide else');
        this.subItems = {}
      }
      
    }
    // console.log('subItems', this.subItems)

    this.isEmpty = Object.keys(this.subItems)
    
  }
```

Template code:

```
<mat-selection-list #parentList [multiple]="false" (click)="onChange(parentList)" class="list1">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let menu of menuList">
    <mat-list-option  [value]="menu" #selectedOpt 
    [ngClass]="{active: selectedOpt.selected}" >
      {{menu.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
  </ng-container>
  
</mat-selection-list>

<mat-selection-list #sub [multiple]="false" class="list2" (click)="onSubChange(sub)">
  <ng-container *ngIf="subItems">
  <ng-container *ngIf="isEmpty.length > 0">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let test of subItems[selected.name]"  [value]="test" #selectedSubOpt [ngClass]="{active: selectedSubOpt.selected}">
      {{test}}
    </mat-list-option>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  
</mat-selection-list>
```

Here is the working demo for the same [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ba6xwz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your code looks good to me, there are some changes needed ;)

- No need of `subItems` member variable. Because `this.selected` already holds value with subMenu. So, you can use `this.selected` only to show the `subMenu`
- No need of more than one `ng-container`. Below check is enough with only one ng-container to display subMenu.

> *ngIf="selected && selected.subMenu && selected.subMenu.length"

- As we don't need of `subItems` member variable. We don't need to update `subitems` with selected parent's subMenu. So the new code will looks like below
- To unselect selected value, you need to call `deselectAll()` method on the `MatSelectionList`

### Forked and working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qgt5ep?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

**HTML**

```
<mat-selection-list #parentList [multiple]="false" (click)="onChange(parentList)" class="list1">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let menu of menuList">
    <mat-list-option [value]="menu" #selectedOpt [ngClass]="{active: selectedOpt.selected}">
      {{menu.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
  </ng-container>

</mat-selection-list>

<mat-selection-list #sub [multiple]="false" class="list2" (click)="onSubChange(sub)">
  <ng-container *ngIf="selected && selected.subMenu && selected.subMenu.length">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let submenu of selected.subMenu" [value]="submenu" #selectedSubOpt [ngClass]="{active: selectedSubOpt.selected}">
      {{submenu}}
    </mat-list-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-selection-list>

<p>
  Option selected: {{parentList.selectedOptions.selected[0]?.value.name}}
</p>
<p>
  Sub selected: {{sub.selectedOptions.selected[0]?.value}}
</p>
```

**Typescript**

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("selectedOpt") selectedOpt;
  @ViewChild("selectedSubOpt") selectedSubOpt;
  menuList: any;
  selected: any;
  subselected: any;

  constructor() {
    this.menuList = [
      {
        name: "Angular"
        //  "subMenu": ["Anguler 1", "Angular 2"]
      },
      {
        name: "Javascript",
        subMenu: ["Jquery", "Ajax"]
      },
      {
        name: "Bootstrap",
        subMenu: ["BootStrap 2", "BootStrap 3"]
      }
    ];
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.selected =
      this.selected === e.selectedOptions.selected[0].value
        ? null
        : e.selectedOptions.selected[0].value;
    if (!this.selected) {
      e.deselectAll();
    }
  }

  onSubChange(sub) {
    this.subselected =
      this.subselected === sub.selectedOptions.selected[0].value
        ? null
        : sub.selectedOptions.selected[0].value;
    if (!this.subselected) {
      sub.deselectAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :), its working as expected.